# Value passed by ajax from Javascript to C#, Replied but not saved

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I pass a value to my C# part with ajax and I get a response back. But I can't save the value or use it in my C# code. More information below:

Ajax Call: (gallery.aspx)

```
    $.ajax({
        url: Url, //assigned previously
        data: 'call=ajax&method=GetList&typeIds=' + typeIds.replace(",",""),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log("From AJAX: " + resp) // this works and shows the result

            },
             error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            }
    });
```

Code Behind (CodeFile):(gallery.aspx.cs)

> Update: Full C# code snippet

```
public partial class gallery : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        public List<string> images = new List<string>();    
        public List<string> imagesList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> filteredImagesList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> testList = new List<string>();
        protected string imagesName;
        protected string filterType;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request["call"].ParseString() == "ajax")
            {
                Response.Write(Request["typeIds"].ParseString().TrimEnd(','), true, ResponseType.Json);
                filterType = Request["typeIds"].ParseString().TrimEnd(',');
            }
            else
            {
                filterType = "Not Assigned!";
            }
        }
}
```

**Output on the page: Not Assigned!**
Meaning `<h1><%=filterType%></h1>` in aspx file returns the else statement from aspx.cs file

But I get the response back in my javascript while `console.log("From AJAX: " + resp)` shows the result.

**BUT** I can't use filtertype's value in my c# codefile.

I can't understand how come the `Response.Write(Request["type"].ParseString().TrimEnd(','), true, ResponseType.Json);` gives back the Request["type"] to js part but don't save it for my codefile. Should it be anything like Response.Read or Response.Save or something?

Does someone know what is going on in here?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by a C# codefile. Are you talking about a code behind file or are you talking about in line C# in a Razor page? Just give use the entire method where your C# snippet came from.

Comment: Yes, its the code behind but I always use CodeFile="myfile.aspx.cs" for @ tag at the top

Comment: Is your C# code in a method, and if it is, can you please update your question with the code which surrounds your C# snippet.

Comment: @Chris I updated my question. Let me know if I should share more information

Comment: What does mean `Output on the page: Not Assigned!`. When do you see this result?

Comment: <h1><%=filterType%></h1> This says Not Assigned and console.log("From AJAX: " + resp) from js returns From AJAX: correct-result I needed to be assigned to filterType

Answer (score 0):

You can store the ajax response in a hidden field and then access that hidden field value in server side code.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />  

$.ajax({
        url: Url, //assigned previously
        data: 'call=ajax&method=GetList&type=' + typeIds.replace(",",""),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                console.log("From AJAX: " + resp) // this works and shows the result
                 $('#<%=HiddenField1.CliendId%>').val(resp);

            },
             error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            }
    });
```

You can then access in server side code like this:

```
HiddenField1.Value
```

Comment: Project crashes when I add asp:HiddenField no error given

Comment: Can you elaborate what does it mean by project crashes

Comment: When I refresh I get 301 error. The project I have once 301 error hits it redirects and doesn't log the error data

Comment: hidden field should not have anything to do with 301 redirect

Comment: I know but strangely I can use asp:label or other asp: properties. But when I do the same trick with asp:label it doesn't work

Comment: `<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />` ensure that there is space before ID

Comment: I tried all kinds of asp:HiddenField previously my initial question is about ajax response and request

Answer (score 0):

OK. It will never be assigned in the way how you did it. Simply because when the page is loading and all controls are rendering no ajax calls are taking into account [Page Life Cycles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)). Because of that on page load `filterType` is not assigned.

Although you have a couple of options

1. Use Ajax with update panel and [PageRequestManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb311028%28v%3Dvs.140%29)
2. Change the value through JQuery or Vanilla JS by using `<%=filterType.ClientID%>`

If you need only front-end representation you can use either option. If you need it for further back-end I'm afraid option 1 only choice for you.

Comment: But how come the response works correctly. Response.Write works fine and writes the desired response back to js

Comment: Because it responded to Ajax request then all controls had been set